# AngularJS how to animate body background (CSS or JS)?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation, gsap

I'd like to animate background image when the view changes. Background image is currently set by a function which is defined in MainController - it looks like that:

```js
// app/js/controllers.js

$scope.getBg = function() {
  return $route.current.scope.pageBg || 'bg-intro';
};
```

it just returns a class name ('pageBg' is defined in each Controller separately) which should be applied to the body:

```
// app/index.html
<body ng-class="getBg()">
...
</body>
```

The CSS classes looks something like that:

```css
.bg-intro {
  background: #4d4638 url(../img/home.jpg) no-repeat top center;
}
```

I tried both CSS and JS ways to solve this but without success.

CSS:

```css
/* app/css/animations.css */

.bg-intro.ng-enter,
.bg-intro.ng-leave {
background: #ffffff;
}

.bg-intro.ng-enter {
animation: 0.5s fade-in;
}

.bg-intro.ng-leave {
animation: 0.5s fade-out;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
from { opacity: 0; }
to { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fade-out {
from { opacity: 1; }
to { opacity: 0; }
}
```

JS (with Greensock):

```
.animation('.bg-intro', function() {
    return {
        enter: function(element, done) {
            TweenMax.set(element, { backgroundColor:"#ffffff"});
            TweenMax.from(element, .5, {alpha:0, ease:Power2.easeInOut, onComplete:done});

            return function(cancel) {
                if(cancel) {
                    element.stop();
                }
            };
        },

        leave: function(element, done) {
            TweenMax.set(element, { backgroundColor:"#ffffff"});
            TweenMax.to(element, .5, {alpha:0, ease:Power2.easeInOut, onComplete:done});

            return function(cancel) {
                if(cancel) {
                    element.stop();
                }
            };
        }
    }})
```

I thought that this would be an easy task and unfortunately it appeares to be to hard for me.

Comment: I assume the `// app/css/animations.css` is not acutally in your css. Because it's not a line comment, but a next construct comment (a comment is `/* */`). The `//` would comment out your `.bg-intro.ng-enter part`.

Comment: If the `pageBg` values defined in each controller is not `bg-intro` and you only have `bg-intro` in your stylesheet, I believe your animations are not going to work.

Comment: @PhilippeBlayo: It's not in animate.css - i added it manually here. Thanks for pointing this out - it could be confusing.

Comment: @ArnelleBalane: yes, I putted just a part of CSS code here - I defined those animations for every view class (in original file).

Comment: I used Greensock , and I preferred to use CSS , because it was more smoother

Answer (score 1):

`ng-enter` and `ng-leave` are applied when you're using directives like `ng-show` etc. In this case, you're just applying a style, so you can achieve what you are trying to do with simple CSS transition on the background element for body:

```
body{
  transition: background ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
```

I recommend [this article](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html) for a more complete overview of Angular animations.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I've read this article before but I couldn't manage to apply these ideas to solve my problem..
As for your solution, it actually work only on page refresh (ctrl+r) and not when I switch the view (no animation then).

Comment: Is that site still up?

Answer (score 0):

You must create a factory that animates your background, and on complete the factory needs to return a promise.  Then using something like Angular UI-Router, you can request a promise before changing views.  Here is an example of the same concepts that I use for my footer to animate open and close when transitioning views.

```
angular.module('App.factory', []).factory("footerUtility", function($window){
var element = document.getElementById('footer-wrapper');
return {
    open : function() {
        TweenMax.to(element,1, {
            delay:1.5,
            maxHeight: '300',
            height: 'auto',
            width: '100%',
            marginTop:'0px',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            ease: Cubic.easeInOut
        });


    },
    close : function(deferred) {
        TweenMax.to(element, .500, { delay:0,maxHeight: 0, height: 0,width: '100%', overflow: 'hidden', ease: Cubic.easeInOut,
            onComplete:function(){
                $window.scrollTo(0,0);
                deferred.resolve('complete');
            }});
    }
}
});
```

Then you would use angular UI-Router to set a enter and leave and a resolove. like so:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('App.home', [])
.config(
['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

        $stateProvider.state("home", {
            abstract: false,
            url: "/home",
            controller: 'homeCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            onExit: ['footerUtility'],
            onEnter: ['footerUtility',
                function (footerUtility) {
                    footerUtility.open();
                }],
            resolve:['footerUtility', '$q', function(footerUtility, $q){
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                footerUtility.close(deferred);
                return deferred.promise;
            }]
        })
    }]
).controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope','$stateParams', '$http', '$location', '$timeout', function($scope, $stateParams, $http, $location, $timeout) {


}]);
```

Hopefully this is a good enough example to get you going with the basics.  you could also pass a color or url into your factory so you could specify the background of the body changing on the way out, and the way in, etc...